# _Imports.razor doesn't work out of the box in WebAssembly project

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, webassembly

All usings in _Imports.razor are unused, I need to add usings in the razor files instead, also even the app template in VS just added the usings to the FetchData.razor for the WeatherForecast demo page because _Imports.razor doesn't work (it also automatically created the _Imorts.razor that is broken)..

#### To Reproduce

Create Blazor Web Assembly app and open the _Imports.razor file.
All the usings are greyed out.

#### Further technical details

- ASP.NET Core 5.0
- WebAssembly App

I did post this issue in project github, however it was closed with no explanation. The issue is there from the beginning with no alteration of code by me.

Comment: This is happening in dotnet7 now.  BlazorWASM.  Must be another bug in VS2022